# Issue with reading maven profile property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, maven

i have a profile in the pom file like the following:

```
<profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <application.domain>mydomain.com</application.domain>
                <application.name>MyApp</application.name>
            </properties>
 </profile>
```

and i read this value in the properties file like the following:

```
${application.name}
first.key =\u0627\u0644\u062E\u0627\u0635 \u0628\u0643 ${application.name} \u0627\u0633\u062A\u0645\u0631 \u0645\u0639 \u062D\u0633\u0627\u0628
second.key=\u061F ${application.name} \u0644\u064A\u0633 \u0644\u062F\u064A\u0643 \u062D\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u0639\u0644\u0649
```

it works fine with the first key and the value is replaced successfully, but with the second one and other keys like it, it didn't work i don't know why, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked fine with me after adding the following plugin in the pom file:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the application name in your properties file with the value in the Maven pom you must:

1. Use @variable@ format in you properties file! It's a Maven variable I understand.
2. activate resource filtering for resources (at least for your properties file)

You should define the proper file encoding for resource filtering (UTF-8 recommended, but anyway the properties files must be in ascii-7 as yours).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Maven filtering mechanism is choking on the Unicode escapes. Why not just spell it out in UTF-8?

```
first.key =الخاص بك ${application.name} استمر مع حساب
second.key=؟ ${application.name} ليس لديك حساب على
```

Comment: No please. Property files must not be in UTF-8... or can they? They should be readable in ascii-7 and \unnnn format. Maven should be configured to read (other) filtered source files in proper encoding.

Comment: @helios Readable? I don't know about you, but I can't read Unicode escapes (nor Arab, but that's a different issue :-)). Seriously: ever since Unicode has been around, I'd say storing files in UTF-8 is good practice and I can't see a reason not to do it (as long as you configure your source encoding properly)

Comment: My comment is not clear at all. What I mean is Java properties files must not contain any non ascii-7 char. If you want to hold a char above that you must use the \u*nnnn* format. It still is ascii-7 (and UTF-8 at the same time ;-) but java.util.Properties will decode the thing properly into memory. If you respect that then Maven will be ok filtering the file (it can asume it's ascii-whatever, iso-8859-whatever or UTF-8). Maven will not try to decode \unnnn format. For Maven it's simply: bar u numbers.

Comment: Properties javadoc tells about the file encoding thing: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: @helios, what do you suggest then ?

Comment: @helios didn't know that, that's awful. I'd say that's a serious bug (or missing feature) in java.util.Properties

Comment: Yep. That's why exist a plugin for Eclipse called ResourceBundleEditor (or something like that) that allows mutiple locale editing at the same time that decodes/encodes the thing properly. But it's tricky if you're not aware!